# How to update a an object field, inside an array that is inside an array

Tags: mongoose

I want to update a `note` inside an array that is inside an array having the name of my list.

I have the `_id` of my user, `name: 'Test'` of the list, the `_id` of the book and the `note` to update to.

My model is as follow :

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    _id,
    ...,
    lists: [
        {
            name: String,
            books: [
                {
                    _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Books' },
                    note: { type : Number, default: null }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

I tried with `$set` and `$push` but got instead an another list with a name 'Test'. I tried as well to search the user _id and manually find in javascript with .filter() to find my books, but there seem to be a solution with Mongoose.

Tried to do the follow query, but without success

```js
({_id: req.myUser._id, 'lists': { $elemMatch: { 'name' : 'General' }}})
```

Example, I want to update `qozirjqzàçorizq` to 15 :

```
{
    _id: qoizrhqzoi, <--------------- I know this
    lists: [
        {
            name:'General', <--------------- I know this
            books: [
                {
                    _id: qozirjqzàçorizq, <---------- I know this
                    note: 12      <-------------- Want to change that
                }
            ]
        },
        {   
            name: 'Perso1'
            books: [
                {
                    _id: 8qzrq654rz,
                    note: 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My json comes in the following format but can be changed to only have the 4 fields _id, name, _id and note.

```
        {
            _id: qozirjqzàçorizq,
            note: 15
        }
```

How do I update this particular field (note) inside two nested arrays ?

EDIT : I've managed to update the the book that is noted, but it does not upsert, it always replace the current one, it's not acting as an array

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {   _id: req.myUser._id,
            "lists" : { $elemMatch : 
                { name: req.params.listName }
            } 
        },
        {
            $set: { 'lists.$.books': req.body}
        },
        {
            new: true,
            upsert: true
        })
    .exec()
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.error(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated it as follow

```
User.findById(id)
        .exec((err, user) => {
            if(user) {
                let added = user.lists.id(req.params.listId).books.addToSet(req.body)
                if(added.length <= 1) {
                    let book = user.lists.id(req.params.listId).books.id(req.params.artworkId)
                    book.note = req.body.note
                    book.lastModified = Date.now()
                }
                user.save()
                res.status(200).json({
                    message : "Success"
                })
            }
        })
```